# HTTP-POST an image to Ruby on Rails app

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, http-post

I have an image in the form of a byte array in java. I'm trying to upload that image to my Ruby on Rails app, which makes use of Paperclip gem. My Rails model looks like this:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

When I execute the java code, I get `HHTTP/1.1 302 Found` response my rails app. 
**Updated java HTTP-Post method.** 
Here's the new java code that I am using for HTTP-Post:

```
public void postFile(byte[] image) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:3000/apps");

    ContentBody cb = new ByteArrayBody(image, "image/jpg", "icon.jpg");
    //ContentBody cb = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(image), "image/jpg", "icon.jpg");

    MultipartEntity mpentity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    mpentity.addPart("image", cb);
    httppost.setEntity(mpentity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
}
```

Here's the new debug on the rails console:

```
Started POST "/apps" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Jan 31 00:26:07 +0000 2011
Processing by AppsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x1041491c8 @content_type=nil, @original_filename="icon.jpg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"icon.jpg\"\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/NU/NUcfnxwVHmmnVUo9JUdNok+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110131-3735-1ylugl7-0>>}
SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.0ms)  describe `apps`
AREL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `apps` (`appName`, `image_file_size`, `created_at`, `image_updated_at`, `image_file_name`, `image_content_type`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2011-01-31 00:26:07', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-01-31 00:26:07')
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
SQL (1.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/apps/36
Completed 302 Found in 18ms
```

Uploading images directly from the browser works like a charm. Here's the implementation of controller/apps_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @app = App.new(params[:app])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @app.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@app, :notice => 'App was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @app, :status => :created, :location => @app }
      format.json  { render :json => @app, :status => :created, :location => @app }        
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @app.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json  { render :json => @app.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }        
    end
  end
end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What HTTP library are you using?

Comment: Apache Commons HTTPClient 4.1

Comment: From the logs it looks like an entry is being inserted to the db and the attachment being saved, can you confirm if that is the case or not? And it would also be interesting to see the create action in AppsController, can you include that in your question as well?

Comment: @DanneManne. Yes, an Entry is being inserted into the db, but the attachment is not being saved. If you look at the debug, you will also notice that all the values are set to null. I have also commented out protect_from_forgery in ApplicationController; before commenting out protect_from_forgery, I was getting invalid authenticity_token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you try to create the App with params[:app] when there are no parameters named app, only image. I think the following in your create action should work instead:

```
@app = App.new(:image => params[:image])
```

Another good thing can be to add the following validation in your App model to make sure that a record is not saved to the database if no image was saved.

```
validates_attachment_presence :image
```